# Controlar el onFragmentResult y volver atrás en el flujo

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, navigationview

Tengo los `Fragments` A, B y C. En el A invoco al B, en el B inserto datos y se los paso al C con la intención de que, después de guardar los datos correctamente, al pulsar un botón se retroceda en el flujo hasta B, comprobar si el resultado es el esperado y volver al A.

El `Fragment C` sería:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FragmentCBinding binding = FragmentCBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

    View view = binding.getRoot();

    ...

    buttonBack = binding.buttonBack;
    buttonConfirm = binding.buttonConfirm;

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(FragmentCViewModel.class);

    ...

    buttonBack.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonConfirm.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonConfirm) {
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String title = textViewTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        String content = textViewContent.getText().toString().trim();

        Note note = new Note(0, title, content, date, id);

        viewModel.saveNote(note).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
            noteSaved -> {
                if (noteSaved) {
                    Bundle result = onButtonConfirmIsPress();

                    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult(REQUEST_KEY, result);
                    getParentFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
            });
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonBack) {
        requireActivity().onBackPressed();
    }
}

public Bundle onButtonConfirmIsPress() {
    Bundle result = new Bundle();

    result.putBoolean(RESULT_KEY, true);

    return result;
}
```

El `Fragment B` sería:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView( @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    getResultListener();

    ...
}

private void getResultListener() {
    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener(REQUEST_KEY, getViewLifecycleOwner(),
        (key, bundle) -> {
            if (bundle.getBoolean(RESULT_KEY)) {
                getParentFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            } else {
                getBundleValues(bundle);
            }
        });
}
```

El problema de hacerlo así es que sí desde el `Fragment A` intento hacer cualquier acción la app se cierra y se muestra el siguiente error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.notes, PID: 29312
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.example.notes:id/action_notesOptions_to_notes cannot be found from
> the current destination Destination(com.example.notes:id/FragmentC)
> label=New note class=com.example.notes.fragment.FragmentC
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:940)
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:877)
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:863)
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1159)
> at com.example.notes.fragment.FragmentA.onClick(FragmentA.java:78)

Básicamente el error dice que en el `Fragment C` no encuentra la acción que he lanzado desde el `Fragment A`, entiendo que se debe a que he retrocedido en el flujo de forma incorrecta.
He probado quitando `getParentFragmentManager().popBackStack();` ya que en la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate?hl=es-419#pass-between-fragments) en la que me he basado para esta implementación lo establece así, y buscando no he encontrado ninguna solución que se pueda aplicar.

¿Alguien sabría decir que estoy haciendo mal?

**Edición**

En el `Fragment C` he modificado la forma de hacer `popBackStack`, recuperándolo de la siguiente manera:

```
NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).popBackStack();
```

En el `Fragment B` he movido la invocación del método `getResultListener` el método `onCreate` y he modificado la implementación de `popBackStack`, así:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getResultListener();
}

private void getResultListener() {
    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener(REQUEST_KEY, this,
        (key, bundle) -> {
            if (bundle.getBoolean(RESULT_KEY)) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).popBackStack();
            } else {
                getBundleValues(bundle);
            }
        });
}
```

Sigue produciéndose el mismo error y no se como arreglarlo.